# Scrapy: Filtered duplicate request

Tags: python, scrapy

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать фильтрацию с повторяющихся request?
Дело в том, что каждый раз, когда заходишь на разные страницы требется вводить логин и пароль и идет перенаправление на страницу входа.

```
Filtered duplicate request: <POST https://member.expireddomains.net/login/> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
```

Мой код:

```
from scrapy import FormRequest
from scrapy import Request

from ..items import GetDomainsItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
import re


class GetUrlDelDomSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'get_domains'

allowed_domains = ["expireddomains.net"]

start_urls = list(map(lambda p: 'https://member.expireddomains.net/domains/expiredcom201612/?start=%s' % p, [0, 25]))

def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield Request(url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)

def parse(self, response):
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                    formnumber=1,
                                    formdata={'login': 'xxx', 'password': '*****', 'rememberme': '2'},
                                    callback=self.parse_login)

def parse_login(self, response):
    if b'The supplied login information are unknown.' not in response.body:
        item = GetDomainsItem()
        for each in response.selector.css('table.base1 tbody '):
            domain_old = each.xpath('tr/td[@class="field_domain"]/a/text()').extract()
            domain_list = list(filter(None,
                                      map(lambda el: el if not re.search('[-\d]', el) and len(el) <= 15 else '',
                                          domain_old)))
            without_dot = list(
                map(lambda dom: '%s%s' % (dom.split('.')[0][0].lower(), dom.split('.')[0][1:]), domain_list))
            item['domain'] = list(
                map(lambda i: ''.join(list(map(lambda j: ' %s' % j.lower() if j.isupper() else j, i))),
                    without_dot))
        return item
```

Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну Вы ведь используете параметр dont_filter здесь:

```
yield Request(url, self.parse, dont_filter=True)
```

Почему же Вы не используете его в конструкторе FormRequest?

```
yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                formnumber=1,
                                formdata={'login': 'xxx', 'password': '*****', 'rememberme': '2'},
                                callback=self.parse_login,
                                dont_filter=True)
```

Comment: добавил dont_filter=True в конструктор FormRequest.
Все равно соскабливает данные только с одной страницы (со второй - 'https://member.expireddomains.net/domains/expiredcom201612/?start=25)
Что может еще мешать выполнять одинаковые запросы?
Спасибо.

Comment: Так у Вас всего две страницы: 0 и 25 :) Вы ведь мапите по списку [0, 25] который является списком из двух элементов... ну вы поняли, я думаю. Это ведь не Хаскель, да и там [0..25] было бы, а Вам нужен `list(range(25))`.

Comment: Лист [0,25] я лишь указал для того, чтобы не захламлять код). Там пагинация идет из ряда page=+25 и вместо функции, которая идет с шагом в 25 и был вставлен этот список только из двух элементов.
Вся проблема уперлась только в то, что данные с первой страницы затираются данными второй. 
Например:
`item['domain'] = ['google.com', 'yahoo.com']
item['domain'] = ['yandex.ru', vk.com']
>> item['domain']
>> ['yandex.ru', vk.com']`